# Installing PHP56 Mongo Driver in my ec2 (centos/linux) instance

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I want to install mongo driver manager as given here http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php

Mongo is already running. pecl is not there in my instance. you can find my phpinfo [here](http://zodiva.com/phpinfo.php)

Please guide me through the necessary steps.

**EDIT**

I have installed pecl,, now I suppose I have to install php-devel but I am getting the following error

```
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56 conflicts with php-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to install pecl using the following list of commands in php-5.6 ec2

> sudo yum install php-pear
>
> sudo yum install php56-devel
>
> sudo yum install gcc
>
> sudo yum install openssl-devel
>
> sudo pecl install mongodb